# Existence&Uniqueness of ivp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, terminology, proof-explanation

I want to determine $a$ so that the existence and uniqueness applies to the initial value problem:

$x'=\frac{3}{2}|x|^{1/3}, x(0)=a$

What is the standard approach when solving this, I'm fairly new to differential equations and struggling with a bit of the theoretical concepts behind them.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\not=0$, the function $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}|x|^{1/3}$ is locally Lipschitzian. So the [theorem of Picard-Lindelof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) guaranties the existence of a unique solution of your problem.

When $a=0$, $f$ is not locally Lipschitzian, so the theorem of Picard-Lindelof is not applicable. Indeed, 
$
\forall k>0,\forall\varepsilon<(\frac{3}{8k})^{\frac{3}{2}},\ x_1,x_2\in]0,\varepsilon[
$ :
\begin{align*}
\vert x_1-x_2\vert&=\vert \sqrt[3]{x_1}-\sqrt[3]{x_2}\vert\vert \sqrt[3]{x_1^2}+\sqrt[3]{x_2^2}+\sqrt[3]{x_1}\sqrt[3]{x_2}\vert&\\
&\leq 4\sqrt[3]{\varepsilon^2}\vert \sqrt[3]{x_1}-\sqrt[3]{x_2}\vert&\\&<\frac{3}{2k}\vert \sqrt[3]{x_1}-\sqrt[3]{x_2}\vert&\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\vert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\vert.&
\end{align*}
You can check easily that $x_{1}\equiv0$ and 
$$
x_{2}(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}
[l]{l}%
0,\ t<0,\\
t^{\frac{3}{2}},\ t\geq0,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
are solutions of the Cauchy problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}
[l]{l}%
x'=\frac{3}{2}|x|^{1/3},\\
x(0)=0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$